# Why can't I assign lambdas to function parameters as a default value?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++20

Take the following function:

```
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) find_median(T begin,
                           T end,
                           bool sorted = false,
                           auto comparison = [](auto a, auto b){return a < b;}){
    assert(begin != nullptr);
    assert(end != nullptr);
    return sorted ? find_median_sorted(begin, end) : find_median_unsorted(begin, end, comparison);
}
```

Note that I set the `comparison` param to a default value `[](auto a, auto b){return a < b;}`. So if I call this function like the following: `find_median(std::addressof(arr), std::addressof(arr[9]))` where `arr` is an `std::array`, this should work. But it doesn't work, does can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can provide a default value for a known type, but you can't provide a default value for a deduced type like this. It's just not something the language supports.

You have to provide a default for the type *and* the value:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename Cmp = std::less<>>
decltype(auto) find_median(T begin,
                           T end,
                           bool sorted = false,
                           Cmp comparison = {})
{
    // ...
}
```